# Send request parallelly for all the values of correlation variable

Tags: jmeter

Below is the scenario (Jmeter Tool)

1. I am capturing one variable (Name as UID) using regex by keeping match number as "-1'
2. I want to create request for each UID, and these requests should go parallel. (Sometimes this count come as 300, sometimes 350 i.e., its dynamic)
3. I used ForEach controller, but requests are going sequentially.
4. When I add Parallel controller under ForEach controller it only send one request and come out of loop.

Can anyone please suggest a way to overcome this problem?

Have an idea like
we can consider using Parallel Sampler, the URLs list can be populated dynamically in the runtime using JSR223 PreProcessor and Groovy language.

Can anyone please help me in writing the script to generate URL list dynamically using correlated value (UID).

Note: URL has parameters and headers to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate the [Parallel Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampler) with some URLs using Groovy you can do something like

```
1.upto(vars.get('yourVar_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    sampler.addURL(vars.get('yourVar_' + index))
})
```

If you want to add headers - the URLs respect [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) given the Parallel Sampler is in the HTTP Header Manager's [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules). Parameters can be passed normally via URL query string:

```
https://example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&etc
```

Comment: same time how to add the url in the above logic u mentioned?

Comment: I need to see the variable and the desired URL in order  to suggest a way to construct it. You can call i.e. [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class function in combination with [strings concatenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter